# Buildfarm Fails because of Downstream Package

Tags: ros, buildfarm, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is

```
 E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-gazebo-taskboard
```

However, no package in nasa_r2_common depends on taskboard. Why does this error occur?

http://jenkins.ros.org/job/prerelease-hydro-nasa_r2_common/ARCH_PARAM=amd64,UBUNTU_PARAM=precise,label=prerelease/2/console

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113316/buildfarm-fails-because-of-downstream-package/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-12-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A prerelease does not only build your selected repositories but also downstream packages which depend on your packages (see "What gets tested" under http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests). In the log you will see that it first builds your packages.

Afterwards it determines which other packages depend on yours:

```
Get list of wet repositories that build-depend on repo list: nasa_r2_common
Build depends_on list of pkg list: rosjava_extras, gazebo_interface, rosjava_core, rosjava_messages, r2_controllers_gazebo, r2_gazebo
```

Then those repos are fetched from their release repositories. Before compiling them their dependencies are being installed from Debian packages and this is when one of them fails to install. And it fails since that package never built before and does not exist in the Debian repository: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html?q=gazebo_taskboard

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1